# Pinia stores - one per component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, pinia

Should we be creating one store per component with Vue 3 and Pinia?
I think too many stores connecting to share state data may become confusing to other devs as the project grows.
Then again, one giant store holding the entire state may be a giant mess as the project grows.
Is there a happy medium or some suggested approaches?

Comment: It totally depends on your case and comes with practice. You need to justify the use of global state vs local state. And Pinia is global by default.

Comment: I thought so - I'm thinking of using both global and local depending on the case. Thanks

Comment: You should not plan stores according to components. You could have a store that doesn't map 1:1 to any component (for e.g. a themeStore). You should plan and create stores according to what global state you have, regardless of the fact that you have a component for it or not. A single store might be sourcing state from multiple components at once according to your use case, in which case you shouldn't split and create a store for each of your component.